# Function definition slays Scala compiler

Tags: scala

Can anyone explain to me why this entry slays the compiler when I type it in to the Scala REPL ?

```
def combination(x: Int, y: Int, f: (Int,Int) => Int) = f(x,y)
```

I am using Scala 2.11.5

```
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(ILoop.scala:904)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:97)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.process(ILoop.scala:904)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.runTarget$1(MainGenericRunner.scala:74)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.run$1(MainGenericRunner.scala:87)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.process(MainGenericRunner.scala:98)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner$.main(MainGenericRunner.scala:103)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.main(MainGenericRunner.scala)

That entry seems to have slain the compiler.  
Shall I replay your session? I can re-run each line except the last one.
```

Comment: It works for me on my scala 2.11.7

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is 2.11.5 bug, and SI-9089 is fixed at 2.11.6.
https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-9089